# Connecting on two separate tickets in CDG. Do I go through passport control?

Tags: cdg, self-transfer

I have an international flight to CDG to terminal 2B and then a domestic flight from terminal 2F on two separate tickets. No checked-in luggage..

Do I go to transfers or do I need to go to passport control?

I have 2.5 hours between these flights, is it enough?

Comment: What country is your international flight from?

Comment: Israel, out of EU..

Comment: Should we understand a **domestic flight** as a flight between 2 points **within** the Schengen Area, for which you must officially enter to catch?

Comment: Yes, domestic within France

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you switch from international to domestic, you will have to go through passport control in any case, and nearly certainly through security in any case as well. It’s just a matter of which route you take to get there.

The most straightforward route is to follow the Baggage claim/Exit signs when you land in 2B. You will go through passport control, walk through baggage claim and customs, and arrive landside.

Turn left and walk a few hundred meters through 2D (the distinction between 2B and 2D is quite blurry nowadays), the train station, and you arrive in 2F. Unless you need to check in at this point, you’ll then go through security and on to your gate. Note that there are two security checkpoints for different sets of gates in 2F.

The total distance is around 1.2 km, so depending on how fast you walk, between 10 and 25 minutes just for the walk (not counting going through passport control or security).

There is probably also the possibility to take an airside shuttle (specifically, the blue shuttle). The order of operations may be different (you will probably go through passport control in 2F rather than 2D), there’s less walking, more waiting. The queues at passport control and security may be shorter (or not — I don’t have much experience transferring in CDG).

While if everything goes fine 2.5 hours are more than enough, that doesn’t leave much buffer if anything goes awry (first plane delayed, long queues at passport control or security…). Remember that unless you have a very flexible ticket, if you’re not at the gate on time, you’ll be considered a no-show, your ticket is very likely to be cancelled, including further legs on the same booking, and you would have to book and pay for a new ticket out of your own pocket, at last minute prices, which can be very expensive. Worst case you may even have to stay overnight at your expense.

Note that I took for granted that you would be able to check-in online or on mobile for your second flight. If not, then you need to have gone through check-in before the check-in deadline, which shortens your critical path even more.

Depending on whether you have a passport which allows you to use the e-gates, where you sit on the first flight, how fast you walk, what day of the week and time of the day you fly, whether you have status allowing you to use fast track for passport control and security, this could range from low risk to very risky. I certainly wouldn’t do that on a Friday afternoon at the start of school holidays.

The usual advice is to have at least 4 hours between flights booked separately, but that of course varies depending on your aversion to risk (and the specific consequences for you in terms of cost and delay).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there a landside shuttle between 2B and 2F? For the airside shuttle I need to follow the transfers sign? The flight is on Tuesday January 30, first flight landing at 13:00.   No for egate.. yes for mobile check in. Would you recommend changing the flights?

Comment: There’s a landside shuttle indeed, but it goes the wrong way around (DACEPF) and makes a long detour via a remote parking. Also when CDG becomes busy the road system between terminals just get clogged, you could be stuck in there for ages. Yes for the airside shuttle follow the Transfers (or is it Connections?) sign. You will need to have a boarding pass for the next flight. Tuesday afternoon on that date should be quiet, but I still would recommend a bit more margin in case there’s an issue with the first flight.

Comment: Are you sure I can use as airside shuttle? I read somewhere 2F is a Schengen terminal and I can't clear immigration there..

Comment: Transfers non-Schengen to Schengen are usually done in the terminal where you land. Haven't been to CDG in a few years, but that's how it was for me back when I did HKG<>BOD via CDG.

Comment: thanks @dda, what does it mean? do I follow the correspondence signs for airside transfer or exit/buggage claim for landside transfer?

Comment: Up to you really although as @jcaron says via the exit it's probably faster. In either case you'll pass through passport control first.

Comment: The blue shuttle (which is outside Schengen) has a stop at 2E (gates LM)/2F. My guess is that it gets you somewhere near the passage between the L gates and 2F, on the side of the L gates (which are ex-Schengen). There’s passport control and security there for people coming from the L gates going to 2F. No idea how busy that is though.

Comment: Not sure what route I would take in your shoes. In a hurry, probably the landside route: it’s a long walk (there are moving walkways between D and the train station and between the train station and F though), but at least you are not dependent on a bus which may or may not be on schedule, and on that date and time passport control in 2B and security in 2F should be quick (but I’m used to e-gates and fast track so I’m biased). If I had all the time in the world I would take the bus because I’m lazy :-)

Comment: its a very short business trip and i decided to not risk it and changed my first flight to 3 hours earlier. leaving me 5.5 hours for this self-transfer. i have the opposite route on the way back (NCE->CDG 2F, CDG->TLV 2B Wed 22:30). i have 3 hours (atleast i'll be with a colleague this time). what is the best route for the opposite direction?

Comment: Wow! That was pretty detailed considering "I don’t have much experience transferring in CDG"! :D

Comment: @GalBen-Haim from 2F you’ll get directly landside. There two options: walk (same thing as on the way out in reverse, but you’ll have passport control somewhere in 2BD), or this time the N1 landside shuttle may make sense.

Comment: And I guess 3 hours should be enough without checked-in luggage, right?

Comment: @GalBen-Haim it’s always the same story: if all goes well it’s more than enough time. The issue is whenever there is a delay on the first flight, if you miss your second flight you are on your own. While you will likely spend less time at passport control (exit rather than entry), in this case your second flight is probably the more expensive and less frequent of the two. Also I realise that flights to Israel have special rules for security reasons which makes things a lot tighter. I’m not even sure you can skip check-in, can you? And the deadline is a lot earlier.

Comment: Sometimes there's an additional security check around the gate. No different instructions for arriving before the flight.  Anyways, I'll take my chances with the 3 hours..